# dataflow start_bundle import and initialization

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

In the code below GcsIO, tarfile, and BytesIO must be imported and instantiated in the start_bundle() or the imports are out of scope on the workers - for instance attempting to include the imports at the top with the other imports causes the code to fail and generate name errors in the worker logs like the following:

`NameError: name 'tarfile' is not defined [while running 'Listen to Pub/Sub topic/Process files-ptransform-21']`

The included code deploys and runs as expected. Because the start_bundle method is called once per bundle, rather than once per element it seems performance may be improved since the objects don't need to be created for every element that is processed. That said - really my question is:

Is the correct pattern is to import and instantiate these objects within the start_bundle method or am I missing something and creating an anti-pattern to get the code to work?

```py
import argparse
import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam import PTransform, DoFn
from apache_beam.io import ReadFromPubSub
from apache_beam.io.gcp.pubsub import PubsubMessage
import logging
import sys


class ProcessFile(DoFn):
    def start_bundle(self):
        from apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio import GcsIO
        import tarfile
        from io import BytesIO
        self.gcs = GcsIO()
        self.tarfile = tarfile
        self.BytesIO = BytesIO
        logging.info(f"GcsIO instance: {self.gcs}")

    def process(self, element, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            file_name = element.attributes['name']
            source_bucket_name = element.attributes['bucket']
            logging.info(f"Processing file: {file_name} in bucket {source_bucket_name}")

            # Get the file size
            source_file_path = f"gs://{source_bucket_name}/{file_name}"
            file_size = self.gcs.size(source_file_path)
            logging.info(f"File size: {file_size} bytes")

            # Read the tar.gz file and upload its contents to the destination bucket
            destination_bucket_name = 'untar'
            with self.gcs.open(source_file_path, 'rb') as f:
                with self.tarfile.open(fileobj=f, mode='r|gz') as tar:
                    for member in tar:
                        if not member.isfile():
                            continue
                        
                        # Read the file from the tarball
                        file_data = tar.extractfile(member).read()
                        
                        # Write the file to the destination bucket
                        destination_file_path = f"gs://{destination_bucket_name}/{member.name}"
                        with self.gcs.open(destination_file_path, 'wb') as dest_file:
                            dest_file.write(file_data)

            logging.info(f"Contents of {file_name} uploaded to bucket {destination_bucket_name}")

            # ...rest of the code...
        except KeyError as e:
            logging.error(f"Required attribute is missing in the message: {e}")


class ReadAndProcessFiles(PTransform):
    def __init__(self, topic):
        self.topic = topic

    def expand(self, pcoll):
        return (
            pcoll
            | "Read from Pub/Sub" >> ReadFromPubSub(topic=self.topic, with_attributes=True).with_output_types(PubsubMessage)
            | "Process files" >> beam.ParDo(ProcessFile())
        )


def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("--project", required=True, help="Google Cloud project ID")
    parser.add_argument("--topic", required=True, help="Pub/Sub topic")
    parser.add_argument("--runner", default="DirectRunner", help="Pipeline runner")
    args, _ = parser.parse_known_args(argv)
    pipeline_options = PipelineOptions(runner=args.runner, project=args.project)
    with beam.Pipeline(options=pipeline_options) as pipeline:
        _ = pipeline | "Listen to Pub/Sub topic" >> ReadAndProcessFiles(topic=args.topic)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have as few instances as possible for your objects, you can use, the `setup` step in the `DoFn` [lifecyle](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/pardo/)

> DoFn.setup(): Called whenever the DoFn instance is deserialized on the
> worker. This means it can be called more than once per worker because
> multiple instances of a given DoFn subclass may be created (e.g., due
> to parallelization, or due to garbage collection after a period of
> disuse). This is a good place to connect to database instances, open
> network connections or other resources.

```py
class ProcessFile(DoFn):
    def setup(self):
        from apache_beam.io.gcp.gcsio import GcsIO
        import tarfile
        from io import BytesIO
        self.gcs = GcsIO()
        self.tarfile = tarfile
        self.BytesIO = BytesIO
        logging.info(f"GcsIO instance: {self.gcs}")
```

For the import, in addition to manage it as you did in the `setup` or `start_bundle`, you can also do the import in the `process` method.

It should also solve the import issue.

You also have an alternative, if you use the native `beam.Map` `ParDo`, you can add the import inside the method invoked in the `map`, example :

```py
def my_method():
   import tarfile
   ....


(p
         | 'Read Json file' >> ReadFromText(input_json_file)
         | 'Map str message to Dict' >> beam.Map(my_method)
....
```